# Google Sheet Formula to extract from | separated hiearchy

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have a hierarchy list separated by |.  The hierarchy is listed as L1|L2|L3|L4|L5 ect.

I'm trying to create a formula to extract the L2 and L3 of the hierarchy.  The best method I've found for now is using the Text to Columns feature in Google Sheets but a formula would be ideal.  Giving some examples below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
=query(arrayformula(if(C2:C="",,split(C2:C,"|"))),"select Col2,Col3")
```

Answer (score 1):

delete everything in A:B range and use:

```
=INDEX(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C, 
 "\|(.+)")&"|", 2), "|")), 9^9, 2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another possible formula with regular expressions, where the first quantifier {n,n} decides which element to extract from the hierarchy, identifying the number of preceding characters that should not be considered: e.g. L2 = {3,3}. In the example is {6,6} for L3

L2 or L3 is the capturing group (\w+), extracted with $1

```
=arrayformula(if(C2:C="","",regexreplace(C2:C,"[\w+\|]{6,6}(\w+){1,1}[\w+\|]{3,}","$1")))
```